# Does Sitecore's EXM render the email body content as HTML?

Tags: exm

In Sitecore's EXM, I am creating a new email campaign as Plain Text Message.

For this message type, the Body field seems to support text only.

However, when I added images and links:
[image]

In the preview mode, it's showing up the links and images:

[image]

**Does this mean that Exm will render these contents as html when being sent as actual email?**

Comment: "Plain Text Message" is just an example that you can sent plain text message. If you put rich content inside then it will send with HTML and images.

Comment: in plain text message that will be rendered as text only.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in my side using Sitecore 8 and Sitecore 9. However this situation is not replicated. Both preview from Content Editor and EXM will show the content as text. Then I send preview message from both instance, the email also come in text.

My suggestion is to try send the preview email or whitelisted contact to test if the content will sent as HTML or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send some email with Html tag then you can use `Simple Html Message` template where you can add message/tag inside rich-text.

[image]

[image]